# Force aspx/cs to be contained in the project dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project `name= extension` that is getting load as an "extension" in other project `name= container`.

When `container` loads the `extension` the `extension` dll is getting copied to `bin` folder in `container` project.

`extension` contains an `page.aspx` with a `cs` file,

How can i "force" the cs file to be contained in the dll  so i could reach it through 'aspx' page?

My final goal - Call an `page.aspx` `http://container/page.aspx?id=1234`

and read the query-string parameter `id` for stream back a content of a pdf

Comment: you do not need the `page.cs` any more after you have the dll. Why would you have included it?

Comment: i want to call the aspx file.. and pass a parmater in queryString and the i am getting the error "cs" don't exist

Comment: What you are looking for is called [_code behind_](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303247)

Comment: You should not use an ASPX page for returning a file. ASPX pages are for when you have a UI, an HTML page. If you want to return a PDF then it's more appropriate to use an HTTP Handler. You can [do that with a .ashx generic handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) file. Or you can [make a regular class that implements IHttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx) and [register it in your configuration file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx).

Comment: My situation is more complicated then that.. i can't just add ashx - i ended up calling an aspx file (his first line) = `<%@ Assembly Name="nameOfMainDll" %>`  and stream the pdf back.. i know it's not the usual approach but this is what i have..